# how to add folder to favorite in windows 7 with C++?

Tags: c++, shell, registry, windows-explorer

In windows 7 SDK sample projects, ExplorerDataProvider, it creates a virtual folder and add this virtual folder under `My Computer` by edit the registry key:

```
#define MYCOMPUTER_NAMESPACE_GUID L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\MyComputer\\NameSpace\\%s"
#define SHELL_EXT_APPROVED        L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Shell Extensions\\Approved\\%s"
```

I want to add this virtual folder under favorite. so I change it to

```
#define MYCOMPUTER_NAMESPACE_GUID L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Shell Folders\\Favorites\\%s"
```

or

```
    #define MYCOMPUTER_NAMESPACE_GUID L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Shell Folders\\Favorites\\NameSpace\\%s"
```

But it doesn't work. nothing show up under my favorite in the windows explorer.
May I ask which registry key or location should I use?

Comment: Windows Explorer Favorites are not stored in the Registry.  They are stored in the `%USERPROFILE%\Links` folder.  Use `IShellLink` to create a shortcut to the virtual folder and then save the shortcut in the `Links` folder.